# How to populate ListView From SQLite in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I have implemented populate list-view from SQLite. When I run my app I got some error like syntax error in create table. I don't know where is the problem.

This is my DataBaseHelper class:

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

    // private String TABLE_NEW_LEAD;
    public DataBaseHelper(Context context, String name,CursorFactory factory, int version) 
    {
               super(context, name, factory, version);
    }
    // Called when no database exists in disk and the helper class needs
    // to create a new one.
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) 
    {
            _db.execSQL(DataBase_Adapter.DATABASE_CREATE_LOGIN);
            //_db.execSQL(DataBase_Adapter.CREATE_NEW_LEAD_TABLE);
            _db.execSQL(DataBase_Adapter.DATABASE_CREATE_DEFINE_PRODUCT);

    }
    // Called when there is a database version mismatch meaning that the version
    // of the database on disk needs to be upgraded to the current version.
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int _oldVersion, int _newVersion) 
    {
            // Log the version upgrade.
            Log.w("TaskDBAdapter", "Upgrading from version " +_oldVersion + " to " +_newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");


            _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + "TEMPLATE");


            _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DataBase_Adapter.TABLE_DEFINE_PRODUCT);
            // Create a new one.
            onCreate(_db);
    }

}
```

This is DataBaseAdapter class

```
public class DataBase_Adapter 
{

        //Database NAme
        static final String DATABASE_NAME = "lead_management.db";

        //Database Version
        static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


        // Variable to hold the database instance
        public  SQLiteDatabase db;

        // Context of the application using the database.
        private final Context context;

        // Database open/upgrade helper
        private DataBaseHelper dbHelper;

        public  DataBase_Adapter(Context _context) 
        {
            context = _context;
            dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        public  DataBase_Adapter open() throws SQLException 
        {
            db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            return this;
        }

        public void close() 
        {
            db.close();
        }

        public  SQLiteDatabase getDatabaseInstance()
        {
            return db;
        }



 //Table Name
        static final String TABLE_DEFINE_PRODUCT="define_product";


         //Creating Define Product Table Column
         static final String KEY_DEFINE_PRODUCT_ID="id";
         static final String KEY_DEFINE_PRODUCT_NAME="name";
         static final String KEY_DEFINE_PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION="description";

        //// SQL Statement to create a Product define Database.
        static final String DATABASE_CREATE_DEFINE_PRODUCT = "CREATE TABLE"+TABLE_DEFINE_PRODUCT+"("+ KEY_DEFINE_PRODUCT_ID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"+ KEY_DEFINE_PRODUCT_NAME + "TEXT,"+ KEY_DEFINE_PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION + "TEXT,"+")";
        //Insert Products

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private final ArrayList<Define_Products_BeanClass> defin_Products_list = new ArrayList<Define_Products_BeanClass>();
        public void insert_Product(Define_Products_BeanClass definProductBeanClass)
        {
             SQLiteDatabase product_db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

             ContentValues contentDefinProduct_Val=new ContentValues();

             contentDefinProduct_Val.put(KEY_DEFINE_PRODUCT_NAME, definProductBeanClass.get_ProductName());
             contentDefinProduct_Val.put(KEY_DEFINE_PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION, definProductBeanClass.get_ProductDescription());
             product_db.insert(TABLE_DEFINE_PRODUCT, null, contentDefinProduct_Val);

             //Close the Database connection
             product_db.close();

        }
```

This is Product List Adapters class:

```
public class Product_List_Adapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<String> Productid_ArrayList;
    private ArrayList<String> ProductName_ArrayList;
    private ArrayList<String> ProductDescription_ArrayList;


    public Product_List_Adapter(Context mContext,
            ArrayList<String> productid_ArrayList,
            ArrayList<String> productName_ArrayList,
            ArrayList<String> productDescription_ArrayList)
    {
        super();
        this.mContext = mContext;
        Productid_ArrayList = productid_ArrayList;
        ProductName_ArrayList = productName_ArrayList;
        ProductDescription_ArrayList = productDescription_ArrayList;
    }




    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Productid_ArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View child, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Holder mHolder;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

        if(child == null)
        {
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            child = layoutInflater .inflate(R.layout.define_products_listrow, null);
            mHolder = new Holder();
            mHolder.txt_product_id = (TextView)child.findViewById(R.id.txt_ProductId);
            mHolder.txt_product_name = (TextView)child.findViewById(R.id.txt_ProductName);
            mHolder.txt_product_description = (TextView)child.findViewById(R.id.txt_ProductDescr);

            child.setTag(mHolder);
        }
        else
        {
            mHolder = (Holder) child.getTag();
        }

        mHolder.txt_product_id.setText(Productid_ArrayList.get(pos));
        mHolder.txt_product_name.setText(ProductName_ArrayList.get(pos));
        mHolder.txt_product_description.setText(ProductDescription_ArrayList.get(pos));

        return child;
    }

    public class Holder {
        TextView txt_product_id;
        TextView txt_product_name;
        TextView txt_product_description;
    }
}
```

This is Product_Activity class:

```
public class DefineProducts_Activity6  extends Activity
{
    Button btnAdd_Products;
    Button btnCancel_Products;

    EditText edTxt_ProductName,edTxt_ProductDescription;
    Dialog myDialog;



    private DataBase_Adapter dbAdapter;
    private SQLiteDatabase dataBase;
    private DataBaseHelper dbHelper;

    private ArrayList<String> productId = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> productName = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> productDescription = new ArrayList<String>();

    private ListView productsList;
    private AlertDialog.Builder build;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.define_products_listview);

        dbAdapter=new DataBase_Adapter(this);
        dbAdapter=dbAdapter.open();

        productsList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.products_List);

        /**__________________Button Add_______________________________________**/

        //Add Products In Listview
        btnAdd_Products=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAdd_DefineProduct);
        btnAdd_Products.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                myDialog=new Dialog(DefineProducts_Activity6.this);
                myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.define_product_details);
                myDialog.setTitle("Defin Product Deatail");
                myDialog.setCancelable(false);

                edTxt_ProductName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_ProductName);
                edTxt_ProductDescription=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_ProductDescription);


                /**_______________________________Button Save________________________________________**/


                Button btn_DefineProduct=(Button)myDialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_Define);
                btn_DefineProduct.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {



                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        String strProductsName = edTxt_ProductName.getText().toString().trim();
                        String strProductDescription = edTxt_ProductDescription.getText().toString().trim();

                        if(strProductsName.length()>0 && strProductDescription.length()>0)
                        {
                            dbAdapter.insert_Product(new Define_Products_BeanClass (strProductsName,strProductDescription));
                            Toast.makeText(DefineProducts_Activity6.this, "Ur Product Is Define", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }


                    }
                });


                /**_______________________________Button Cancel ________________________________________**/

                btnCancel_Products=(Button)myDialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel_Define);
                btnCancel_Products.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        myDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                myDialog.show();

            }
        });

        /**_______________________________________________________________________**/
    }


     // displays data from SQLite

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void displayData()
    {
        dataBase = dbHelper . getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor mCursor = dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DataBase_Adapter.TABLE_DEFINE_PRODUCT , null);

        productId.clear();
        productName.clear();
        productDescription.clear();

        if(mCursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                productId.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DataBase_Adapter.KEY_DEFINE_PRODUCT_ID)));
                productName.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DataBase_Adapter.KEY_DEFINE_PRODUCT_NAME)));
                productDescription.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DataBase_Adapter.KEY_DEFINE_PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION)));

                }while (mCursor.moveToNext());
        }

        Product_List_Adapter productAdapter = new Product_List_Adapter(DefineProducts_Activity6.this ,productId ,productName , productDescription);

        productsList.setAdapter(productAdapter);

        mCursor.close();


    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        displayData();
        super.onResume();
    }


}
```

This is my Log Cat, why am I unable to resume my activity?

```
.11-06 12:57:32.389: W/dalvikvm(11676): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
11-06 12:57:32.399: E/AndroidRuntime(11676): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-06 12:57:32.399: E/AndroidRuntime(11676): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.leadmgmt/com.leadmgmt.DefineProducts_Activity6}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-06 12:57:32.399: E/AndroidRuntime(11676):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2120)
11-06 12:57:32.399: E/AndroidRuntime(11676):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
11-06 12:57:32.399: E/AndroidRuntime(11676):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1668)
11-06 12:57:32.399: E/AndroidRuntime(11676):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
11-06 12:57:32.399: E/AndroidRuntime(11676):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
11-06 12:57:32.399: E/AndroidRuntime(11676):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-06 12:57:32.399: E/AndroidRuntime(11676):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-06 12:57:32.399: E/AndroidRuntime(11676):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-06 12:57:32.399: E/AndroidRuntime(11676):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-06 12:57:32.399: E/AndroidRuntime(11676):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-06 12:57:32.399: E/AndroidRuntime(11676):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-06 12:57:32.399: E/AndroidRuntime(11676):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-06 12:57:32.399: E/AndroidRuntime(11676):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-06 12:57:32.399: E/AndroidRuntime(11676): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-06 12:57:32.399: E/AndroidRuntime(11676):    at com.leadmgmt.DefineProducts_Activity6.displayData(DefineProducts_Activity6.java:80)
11-06 12:57:32.399: E/AndroidRuntime(11676):    at com.leadmgmt.DefineProducts_Activity6.onResume(DefineProducts_Activity6.java:74)
11-06 12:57:32.399: E/AndroidRuntime(11676):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1150)
11-06 12:57:32.399: E/AndroidRuntime(11676):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3832)
11-06 12:57:32.399: E/AndroidRuntime(11676):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
11-06 12:57:32.399: E/AndroidRuntime(11676):    ... 12 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Table like this.

```
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_DEFINE_PRODUCT = " CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_DEFINE_PRODUCT + "(" + KEY_DEFINE_PRODUCT_ID
        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + KEY_DEFINE_PRODUCT_NAME + " TEXT, "
        + KEY_DEFINE_PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT " + ")";
```

You haven't left the space between the fields and variable names.

Comment: But still i got runtime Exception at line  @Override
 protected void onResume() {
  displayData();
  super.onResume();
 }

Comment: I want display data in listview when i Click on my custom dialog button (btn_DefineProduct). I was trying but got nullPointerException.Where i have call displayData(); method .

Comment: Why unable to resume() activity

Comment: Please post stack trace

Comment: `edTxt_ProductName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_ProductName);
                edTxt_ProductDescription=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_ProductDescription);`  Replace the above line by the following : `edTxt_ProductName=(EditText)myDialog.findViewById(R.id.editText_ProductName);
                edTxt_ProductDescription=(EditText)myDialog.findViewById(R.id.editText_ProductDescription);` You have to specify the dialog name. There was no proper initialization. Please check this and let me know. If it works, Please accept this answer.

Comment: Yes My data is save in database but data is not display in the listview.I have to call my displayData() method in my dialog button.But it does not work.How can do this.